# Firebird client installation

Tags: c#, .net, database, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to deploy my Application that uses a Firebird v2.5 database to a client machine.

I am trying to use a minimum installation, without the need to run any other installers.  From what I gather, all I need to do is copy the "FBClient.dll" to the target application folder (which includes firebird database file).  I have tried this and it still reports an error about not being able to find the correct .net data provider.

eg

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\myApp.exe 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\fbDatabase.fdb 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\fbclient.dll
```

The error produced is:

**Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.**

Also have copied, renamed and included fbclient.dll as fbembed.dll

I have also tried to copy a bunch of other files to the app directory, as well as placing fbclient.dll into the c:\, c:\windows, c:\windows\system.

I also tried installing the client installation, with no joy too.

Is there a way, that I can use the firebird database, without manually editing the machine.config files or using the gac and going through the hell that I went through to install firebird on the dev machine?  I want an application that a user can install, not requiring that it be installed by a developer.

Please note, the application that I am writing is for a single machine, single user environment, who knows how to double click the install button, with the attention span of a gnat, that if required to do more than double click install and then press GO, will simply get bored and press the cancel, forget it button.

I add the file "FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll" to the application folder and I no longer get the Data provider error, instead I get the following

```
"Unable to complete network request to host \"DevMachine\"."

at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsConnection.Connect()
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateManagedDatabase(FbConnectionString options)
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateDatabase(FbConnectionString options)
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
```

I am trying to connect with the following

```
string file = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\Test.FDB;";
FbConnection con = new FbConnection("User=SYSDBA;" + "Password=masterkey;" + "Database=" + file + "DataSource=Dev-VS-W7VM;" + "Port3050;" + "Dialect=3;" + "Charset=ISO8859_1;");
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

I have included FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient in my project and installation folder (..\MyApp)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Somewhat lacking in detail here. Surely you could be use copy/paste to provide the exact precise error message. If you can't use copy/paste then copy it vertbatim.

Comment: Copying the `FBClient.dll` into your app's folder is only a solution if you're using the client API directly. If you're using it via C#, and using a Firebird .NET data provider, you still have to install that data provider and register it as an available assembly. (Which, BTW, is just what the error message is telling you - that the .NET data provider couldn't be found or loaded.)

Comment: I want a solution to use a firebird database without having to use the GAC or mess with machine.config files on the target machine.  A stand alone solution is required, with a simple installer that any jack can install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to grap a [zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/2.7.0/NETProvider-2.7.0.zip/download) and copy FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll to bin folder.

I wonder how you wrote your application that it works without the file (probably installed .msi) :)

Comment: I am making progress with this, I hadn't thought of copying this file along with the application.  No data provider error, just won't connect now for some reason, need to investigate further as to why.

Comment: Make sure your project reference this dll. How your code communicate with db? How's it possible you could've compiled your code and yet you don't have this .dll?

Comment: string file = @"C:\Test.FDB;";FbConnection con = new FbConnection("User=SYSDBA;" + "Password=masterkey;" + "Database=" + file + "DataSource=DevMachine;" + "Port3050;" + "Dialect=3;" + "Charset=ISO8859_1;");
            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

Comment: So that means, you already have to have this installed on your machine. Just make sure to deploy this dll. Did you do it? It's 22 hours already:)

Comment: I do not have firebird installed on the client machine, only the dev machine.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to install .net provider 
http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/

Answer (score 1):

The database file resides next to your application's exe module. So, you need in local server running or embedded server in order to work with data. For embedded server a minimal set of files is (specifed relatively to an application folder):

```
\UDF (folder with UDF needed if any)
\Intl (with contents from FB installation)
fbembed.dll
firebird.msg
ib_util.dll
icudt30.dll
icuin30.dll
icuuc30.dll
Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest
msvcp80.dll
msvcr80.dll
```

for a full scale server (i.e. not an embedded) a list of files would be:

```
\UDF (folder with UDF needed if any)
\Intl (with contents from FB installation)
fbserver.exe or fb_inet_server.exe
fbclient.dll
firebird.msg
ib_util.dll
icudt30.dll
icuin30.dll
icuuc30.dll
Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest
msvcp80.dll
msvcr80.dll
security2.fdb
firebird.conf   (if non default parameters used)
```

But then you would need in setting up service record for FB
or start it as an application before your application start.

Installation of the Firebird as a service could be done with 
**instsvc.exe** utility. Appropriate commands:

```
  instsvc install -s -a
  instsvc start
```

Comment: I have all these files in the app directory.  I don't want to run firebird as a service, neither install it as a server.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should take care of two things:

1. FileName must be a local file, not in a shared folder from another server.
2. Appending the firebird server IP before the filename. If you are running your app always in the firebird server, or you are using embeded `fbclient.dll`, than it should be like

   FbConnection con = new FbConnection("User=SYSDBA;" + "Password=masterkey;" + "Database=localhost:" + file + "DataSource=Dev-VS-W7VM;" + "Port3050;" + "Dialect=3;" + "Charset=ISO8859_1;");

Some `fbclient.dll` version will allow you not to add localhost and still connect on local files, or use `\\servername\c:\filename` format instead of `localhost:c:\filename`, but it is deprecated and not supposed to work anymore (and can work depending on windows version).